# expect error in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

```
 VAR1=$(expect -c '
     spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa -f '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_ID"' -N '' -q 
     expect -exact "Generating public/private rsa key pair.\r
     Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):"
     sleep 5
     send "\r";
     expect "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): "
     sleep 5
     send "\r";
     expect "Enter same passphrase again: "
     sleep 5
     send  "\r";
     ')
```

Here is my command in bash that responses the ssh-keygen questions.This code works on my machine even if i delete the "sleep" lines.But on another machine it does not work.It gives the error

```
  send: spawn id exp6 not open
     while executing
   "send "\r""
```

what is the problem

UPDATE:I works well on ubuntu but not on Centos. The expect versions are same

UPDATE:I fixed it.the problem is, with _N option it provides a passphrase pass and with this code I give it as "".then it expects wrongly .the last of the code that works is;

```
   VAR1=$(expect -c '
     spawn ssh-keygen -t rsa -f '"$SSH_KEY_PATH_ID"' -q 
     expect -exact "Generating public/private rsa key pair.\r
     Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):"
     send "\r";
     expect "Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): "
     send "\r";
     expect "Enter same passphrase again: "
     send  "\r";
     ')
```

Comment: What operating systems are the two machines running?

Comment: @chepner working is ubuntu, not-working is centos5

Comment: Since you're specifying an output-file when you call `ssh-keygen` (namely, `$SSH_KEY_PATH_ID`), why would you expect to receive a message asking you for the output-file?

Comment: Turn on exp_internal 1 to find exactly what it is matching. If you have to `sleep 5` after every command then the odds are that you aren't doing your expect statements correctly.  Expect times out after 10 seconds, you can change this by doing `set timeout #`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file has POSIX line endings (\r) and not DOS line endings (\r\n)